# Basic PayPal Checkout Button giving a 500 internal server error in Firefox

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout, paypal

I am using Basic PayPal Checkout Button (data-version-4) with jason payload to do a payment against the 'sandbox'. All the code works fine until it gets to the point of 'Confirm' or 'Pay now' within the PayPal-Pop-Up (Lightbox) ... at this point the Pop-Up closes and no further calls are made to the Button (as example: onAuthorize is not initiated).

At this point the console shows several a warning and errors after 3 x apy_retry. Is this a known issue or does someone have a suggestion on this?

Any help is welcome and thank you very much in advance,
Christian

UPDATE: in Google Chrome (Version 54) it is possible to complete the payment, i am having the errors just within Firefox V49.0.2

**Warning**

```
missing_csrf_jwt Object { timestamp=1479294755397, windowID="5fbc81d2c8", pageID="3768daa62d"}
```

**Error**

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/payment/PAY-1UH37573M6748251ALAWD6BI?"

http_response_500 Object { timestamp=1479294756872, windowID="5fbc81d2c8", pageID="3768daa62d"}
```

**Response of the GET Payment request from button.js**

```
{"ack":"error","message":"Unhandled api error","meta":{"calc":"5c86b8d3140ef","rlog":"rKGmcXTB%2B2NqZAMhrf0E %2BSi2kRuzAYN1zBd6UkYGjcFtNQ0WfaI3FHIbPIRTaJRcwP4CM4%2FkeW05efr7awS8xw_1586cc53450"},"server":"Wb_7k zG8hs8iXSTxTssRX7gAbhKsGUveN-Qi5qR4xO-eChao8SHpy7dW9-lcr1X7z1Ex578DclpDjpNeK6E56fHpDAqRWL8SI0Od4rpHe HT57pjggRD85TXSwGA9IYgdTw8WLisakLokxa9yxvmsjiYYO9Sf8Hnb4sanRFuPznDh8b4zEXUgz2kxautGGtS3lTXJjgK9TVqouGCqrStk_j4GQC1ssToOZ0n6am" }
```

**Console**

[Screenshot of the console Dev Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZxJT.jpg)

Comment: only on Firefox, you test it in chrome?? check if firefox are excluded on firewall or allow to work with network

Comment: Thank you for these suggestions Walter. I tested it in Chrome too, the payment finalized without errors. I also checked the my firewall settings, as i noticed that all the previous function calls to the PayPal REST Backend went through, I was sure that the communication with the server should not be the cause for the errors.
After some help and feedback from paypal itself yesterday evening they were able to solve the problem on serverside.
Anyway, thank you for your suggestions, the where very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your developer console says (in German, I believe) there is an issue with Strict-Transport-Security. This is almost certainly your problem because the policy on handling this error differs from browser to browser.

I also see that the Paypal API is on an https url. Is the request originating from your browser in an http (without the s) setting? In which case this may be the problem, as you would want a request to a secure API to also originate from an encrypted, secure source.

EDIT: You may also want to look at LetsEncrypt which gives developers such as yourself access to free, extremely easy to setup SSL certificates.

Comment: Thank you C Hunter. I had noticed the warnings regarding the Strict-Transport-Security too, but was not able to relate them as part of the problem. But your argumentation regarding SSL seems logical and we will try to elemintate this aspect and get rid of these warnings.
Meanwhile it showed up that the cause for the error was indeed an issue on paypal server. I was able to get help from paypal team member and they managed to solve the issue serverside. Details [here](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/105)
Anyway, thank you for your time and suggestions, the where very welcome.